# make section show with a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a section appear when my button is clicked and instead I am getting a blank screen. I am not sure why this is. Any suggestions would be helpful. I am trying to display the arnold-page div.

```
<section class="middlePage"><!-- START MIDDLE SECTION -->
            <div class="album-nav">
        <button class="arnold">Arnold</button>
        <button class="cats">Cats</button>
        <button class="dogs">Dogs</button>
        <button class="batman">Batman</button>
        <button class="lions">Lions</button>
        <button class="tigers">Tigers</button>
    </div>




    <div class="arnold-page">   <!-- START DIV display-on --><h1>Arnold</h1>
        <div id="arnold1">
            <a href="#"><img src=" "></a>
            <p>Photo 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="arnold2">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/arnold.jpg"></a>
            <p>Photo 2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="arnold3"> 
            <a href="#"><img src=" "></a>
            <p>Photo 3</p>
        </div>

        <div id="arnold4">
            <a href="#"><img src=" "></a>
            <p>Photo 4</p>
        </div>

        <div id="arnold5">
            <a href="#"><img src=" "></a>
            <p>Photo 5</p>
        </div>

        <div id="arnold6">
            <a href="#"><img src=" "></a>
            <p>Photo 6</p>
        </div>


    </div> <!-- END DIV display-on -->


</section><!-- END MIDDLE SECTION -->

    backButton1.on('click', function() {
    bottomPage1.hide();
    middlePage.hide();
    arnoldPage.show();
});
```

Comment: where is your script?

Comment: Please show the script that you have written to do so.

Comment: where is the button?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Script

```
$(function(){

  //Default hide section
 $(".arnold-page").hide();
 $(".arnold").on("click",function()
 {
  $(".arnold-page").show()
 });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by setting the display property to none, and on clicking the button, change the display property to block or inline.

```
<!--Jquery -->

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".arnold-page").css("display","none");
    $(".arnold").click(function(){
     $(".arnold-page").css("display","block");
    });
 });
```